# Move Dictionary Keys to lis for particular values

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I trying to make this code work:

```
civil_freq= {   '430.00': ['aaa'], 
                '430.02': ['aaa'], 
                '430.04': ['aaa'], 
                '430.06': ['bbb'], 
                '430.08': ['bbb'], 
                '430.10': ['bbb'], 
                '430.12': ['none'], 
                '430.14': ['none']}
person_freq=[]
person = 'bbb'
for key in civil_freq:
    if civil_freq[key] == person:
        person_freq.append(civil_freq.get(key))

print(person_freq)
```

it return empty list, but I need smth like

```
['430.06', '430.08', '430.10']
```

Comment: What about `if civil_freq[key][0] == person:` since the value of the dictionary is an array. And `person_freq.append(civil_freq[key][0])`;

Comment: it returns ['bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue: You're storing the persons names in a list (within your `civil_freq` dictionary) but comparing it with a string (variable `person`). This comparison won't work.

Try this:

```py
person = ["bbb"]
for k, v in civil_freq.items():
    if v == person:
        person_freq.append(k)

print(person_freq)
```

or change the values within your dictionary from lists to strings!

Comment: its work! Thank you. This dictionary is a result of import from csv, maybe i should find another way to do it...